# Dependent (Chained) Dropdown in CakePHP 3.8.0 using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm new to CakePHP and ajax. I'm trying to figure out how to utilize AJAX to make dependent (chained) dropdown in CakePHP 3.8.0.

I'm making a few tables for example to learn how to build the chained dropdown menu. I have three tables `models`, `chapters`, `userinputs`. In the `Userinputs` table, I would to chapter to load based on model. Right now all models and all chapters are shown. This is how they're all connected. 
[how all three tables are connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO9HT.png)

I've been looking at some examples online and tried to apply them into my code but nothing seems to be working. This is my add.ctp of my `Userinputs` table.

```
<div class="userinputs form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
<?= $this->Form->create($userinput, ['type' => 'file', 'class' => 'ajax_page']) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Userinput') ?><div class="ajax_loading_image"></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('model_id', ['options' => $models, 'empty' => true, 'id'=>'models']);
        echo $this->Form->control('chapter_id', ['options' => $chapters, 'empty' => true, 'id'=>'chapters']);
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I also added this script at the end of add.ctp of `Userinputs` table

```js
<script>
    $("#models").on('change',function() {
        var id = $(this).val();

        $("#chapters").find('option').remove();
        if (id) {
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                dataType:'json',
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "Userinputs", "action" => "getChapters")); ?>' ,
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    //$("#loding1").hide();
                    $.each(html, function(key, value) {              
                        //alert(key);
                        //alert(value);
                        //$('<option>').val('').text('select');
                        $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#chapters"));

                    });
                } 
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

In the controller of my `Userinputs`, I added a public function

```
public function getChapters() 
{ 
    $id = $this->request->data('id'); 
    $chapters = $this->Chapters->find('all', [ 'conditions' => [ 'model_id' => $id ] ]); 
    echo json_encode($chapters); 
}
```

Please take a look at my codes and please assist me on how to get this working properly. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See also [this](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/chained-dropdowns) example and the open source code behind it linked there on how to get those to work.

Comment: @mark Is the guide in your blog still good to use to apply the source code?

Comment: It works with jquery, so why not :)

Comment: You may use [chained](https://appelsiini.net/projects/chained/)

Comment: @tarikul05 Is there an example out there that I can follow to apply what you linked with cakePHP?

Comment: @user3746801 Here is and example you can check this [Dropdown Cakephp with Chained](http://mzm-cakephp.blogspot.com/2015/03/dropdown-cakephp-with-chained-selects.html)